# Merge all Outlook inboxes in search

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

I found a useful tutorial for combining the inboxes of all email accounts at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8m6HorjaNA

It cleverly operates by running a search for "folder:inbox received:today" and then clicking the dropdown to indicate search in all folders. One can then return to "recent searches" and click again the following day or create the following macro.

VBA code for combining all:

```
Sub UnifiedInbox ()
Dim myO1App As New Outlook.Application
txtSearch = “folder:inbox received:today”
MyO1App.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, o1ScopeAllFolders
Set myO1App = Nothing
End Sub
```

HERE'S the problem with both. When you click "recent search" it defaults to current mailbox, requiring you to click the drop-down and change to "all mailboxes" and running the macro only searches in the current mailbox. I tried to all "mailboxes:all" to the txtSearch but that is obviously not the right language.

Comment: Do all the inboxes belong to the same account ?

Comment: You can refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549938/vba-search-in-outlook